# Finding roots of a fourth degree equation having arbitrary constant

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, roots

The below sum is from Linear differential equations with constant coefficients.

Solve.

D^4 + k = 0

I have to get the general solution for it . I am stuck in finding the roots of this equation .

Comment: Can you find the roots of the polynomial $\mathrm X^4 + k$ ?

Comment: no, i am stuck there itself

Comment: Find one root and multiply it by the roots of unity i.e the solutions of the equation $\mathrm X^4  = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use deMoivre's formula to get the four fourth roots of unity:

$$\xi_i = \cos\left(\frac{2\pi i}{4}\right) + i\sin\left(\frac{2\pi i}{4}\right).$$
In this case these are particularly simple: $1, -1, i, -i$.

Then all roots of the equation $x^4 = -k$ are given by $x = \xi_i r$, where $r$ is one particular root.

If $k$ is positive, you can take $r=k^{1/4}$; if $k$ is negative, $r = (-k)^{1/4}\left(\cos\frac{2\pi}{8} + i \sin \frac{2\pi}{8}\right)$.

Comment: so does this mean , i have to consider two cases ?

Comment: Pretty much. If you want a single formula you can express $k$ in polar form with a single formula using shenanigans like $k = |k|e^{i \arccos(k/|k|)}$.